# How to filter out strings with trailing dot using str.contains()

Tags: python, pandas

In this example I'm trying to filter out all websites with tld such as co.uk or co.at but not .com or .co

I've used the following method:

`df.loc[~df['Website'].str.contains('.co.')]`

This fails to work and matches .com and .co even if dots are escaped. Why? and what would be a better solution?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data showing the problem?

Comment: [`regex=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`regex` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to `False`:

> `regex` bool, default True
>
> - If True, assumes the pat is a regular expression.
> - If False, treats the pat as a literal string.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Website': ['www.google.com', 'www.amazon.co.uk', 'www.yahoo.co.in', 'www.microsoft.com']})
df[~df['Website'].str.contains('.co.', regex=False)]
```

Output:

```
    Website
0   www.google.com
3   www.microsoft.com
```

Comment: @BigBen voted to close as dupe.